# Please help me to understand the PHP code? The massage section mysql_error()

Tags: php

```
<?php

require_once 'login.php';

$conn = new mysqli($hn,$un,$pw,$db);

if ($conn->connect_error) die ($conn->connect_error); //understood

function mysql_fatal_error($msg) {

$msg2 = mysql_error();//dint get it...

echo <<< _END
We are sorry, but it was not possible to complete
the requested task. The error message we got was:
<p>$msg: $msg2</p> //dint get it..
Please click the back button on your browser
and try again. If you are still having problems,
please <a href="mailto:admin@server.com">email
our administrator</a>. Thank you.
_END;

}


?>
```

Please help me understand the second part of the above code. Being specific i understood upto die. But instead of that when i need to return some msg to user i dont get that those sections. I have made comments the line i dint understand.

Comment: I guess this is not your own code. Best advice : walk away.  Mixes mysql (deprecated) and mysqli.

Comment: You defined a user function mysql_fatal_error, and inside it checks the deprecated mysql_error function for an error and then echos out a string? You should just remove mysql_fatal_error function, its not used.

Comment: RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: dear thanks for the advice. But basically I want to do or between two parts in program. means incase I  use connect_error test  and dont use die part. instead of that want show some massage to user. in that case how the function will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`die()` in php is a function which ends execution and prints out the argument passed in parameter. In your case `$conn->connect_error` is the text you will print. The remaining code is not called anywhere thus it is useless. So I think what you want to do is changing :

```
die ($conn->connect_error);
```

into :

```
die ( mysql_fatal_error( $conn->connect_error ) );
```

So the die function will print out the return of `mysql_fatal_error`, in which you pass the mysqli `connect_error` string.

Inside the `mysql_fatal_error` function, basically, what it does is this: it gets the last occurred MySQL error and puts it in `$msg2`. Then a message is constructed in which `$msg` and `$msg2` are inserted. The echo function will then print the whole message.

Note that the function could have just returned the string to the `die` function instead of echo the message and it would have been correct. Instead it's the function who prints the text and doesn't return anything, so the die function doesn't print. The two ways are correct and works.